# ActiveMQ MUltiple subscriptions freezes application

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have an application which tries to subscribes to a lot of different topics.

The server side publishes a lot of messages through these topics and as soon as the application starts subscribing, it receives so many messages that the application cannot even reach the end of the subscription function.

It seems that the OnMessage Listener is flooded so much (the listener is the class which is trying to subscribe itself ot all the topics).

So basically is there a way to stop the reception of messages until I have subscribed to all of the topics? Or am I missing something there?

The thread trying to subsscribe to all of the topics never get the processor again.
(If the server is down, the subscription is fine since it does not receive anything so it does not lose the processing power..)

Thank you in advance.

Paul.

Answer (score 1):

You could try lower the prefetch limit of the consumers, this would prevent the broker from attempting to dispatch so many messages when they are created which should help reduce the flooding issue you are seeing.

Here's some documentation that might help.
http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

Tim -
www.fusesource.com

Comment: I am actually using Topics and not Queues. I am not interested in keeping track of all the messages. I don't even care of the messages I receive during my subscriptions.

Comment: Setting the prefetch has nothing to do with keeping track of messages, it merely regulates how many messages the broker will attempt to spool up at the client per subscription.  If you are creating large numbers of subscriptions to highly active destinations then you should set a low prefetch to reduce the amount of traffic that the client receives at the start of the subscription, this will lower the over CPU overhead you are seeing.  Read the article at the link I gave you it explains things quite well.